# Combining "Gated Checkin" and "Continuious Integration" Builds in Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild, gated-checkin

> this Question moved to 
>   [how to prevent an Gated Check-In to put the Keyword ***NO_CI*** in the Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106023/how-to-prevent-an-gated-chech-in-to-put-the-keyword-no-ci-in-the-comment)
>
> where I put the Question in more detail with my gained knowledge

For ensuring Code Quality and Unit Testing I habe established a Gated Check-In Build in my Project.

Also there is another Build Definition to be triggered by Check-In (Continuous Integration Build), which I want to have build after Check-In.

My expectation was, that The Gated Check in was executed and after successful Build and Commit (by the Build Service User) the other Build is Triggered.

But this is not the Case.

Does any one have an Idea how i get this working, that the Continuous Integration Builds are also triggered by Check-In from the Build Service

Comment: Out of curiosity, why two different builds?  Is the post-checkin CI build a larger scope than the Gated build?

Comment: The Gated Check-In goes over the whole solution, builds all Projects, and executes Unit Tests, as an Quality Step before allowing Code to be Checked-In. - After success I want to launch Builds of selected Projectes, which are stored in seperate folders and can be tested in seperate steps and beeing indiviually marked for Build Quality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is expected that after a Gated-Build happens & succeeds - nothing else happens after that automatically. 
TFS goes to the extend of actually placing a trailer in the commit comments, the infamous `***NO_CI***` that actually tells TFS not to trigger a CI-build after this specific commit.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829305/what-does-no-ci-stand-for) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044776/why-is-no-ci-still-causing-a-continuous-intregration-build) for further descriptions on how it works.
 In fact, if you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054725/728929) answer, you might find a way to get what you 're after: what @dkpatt did wrong, might be your solution.

Comment: Many thanks für this answer! This seems to be the problem. But how do I have to change my Process Template not to write add the ***NO-CI*** Key word in my Check-In ? Ich copied the Default Process Template and looked through the Workflow. At the End i find an activity which in german is called "abgegrenzte Änderungen einchecken" transated I would call it "check-in gated build" where I can not set up anything except "ignoreErrors" and "UpdateWorkItems" (In the Default Template it is at the very bottom).

Comment: I found accourding to pantelifs Answer the following Article discribing that there is an Variable for the NO_CI Comment, may be this is one step to a solution, but I do not know where i can modidy it...?! [link to the Article](http://intovsts.net/2010/04/18/the-gated-check-in-build-in-tfs2010/) or maybe i an on the wrong way and there is an easier way to disable it

Answer (score 0):

How to remove the NO_CI from a build--

1. Open the build template (e.g. DefaultTemplate) in WorkFlow.
2. Search (Current Document/Current Window) for "NoCIOption".
3. The Container should be labeled "GetWorkspace" of type SyncWorkspace.
4. Open Properties (F4).
5. Set the value of NoCIOption to False.
6. Save the build template.